# Visual Studio Code глобальные настройки eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

Настраиваю eslint в редакторе, по мануалу https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals :

В моем конфиге выглядит так:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "globals": {        
      "$": true,
      "moment": true
},
...
```

При таких настройках VS Code выдает ошибку:

```
(options.globals || []).reduce is not a function
```

Как настроить глобальный конфиг eslint в VS Code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, решение достаточно неожиданно и найдено здесь https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/6922

Т.е. предлагается заменить объект глобальных настроек на массив, и теперь с учетом этого, мой конфиг выглядит так:

```
"eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "globals": [        
      "$",
      "moment"       
    ],
...
```

Надеюсь кому-то ответ сократит время поиска решения проблемы.